# how to find size of HTML file and data transfer rate

Tags: java, httpclient

I want to find the size of an HTML file without HTTP headers and data transfer rate. Below is my code;

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HttpCon 
{
  public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException 
  {
    Socket s = null;

    try 
    {
        String host = "host1";
        String file = "file1";
        int port = 80;

        s = new Socket(host, port);

        OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter outw = new PrintWriter(out, false);
        outw.print("GET " + file + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        outw.print("Host: " + host + ":" + port + "\r\n");
        outw.print("Accept: text/plain, text/html, text/*\r\n");
        outw.print("\r\n");
        outw.flush();           

        InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inr);
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
                System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();       

    } 

  }
}
```

But I do not have any idea how to do this. Is there a source code that I can look at or any resource that I can apply?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a large paste of code, and also say you have no idea how to do this. Could you be more specific as to which part of this you have no idea how to do?

Comment: @zmccord  There are 2 problems actually. First one is , I need to find the size of the HTML file without HTTP headers that I download with this code. Is there a specific function or any other recommendations? Second one is , after calculating size , I have to find data transfer rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for shouldn't be much of a problem. Read the lines until you read an empty line -- that's where the headers end. After that just go on reading and count all the characters you have read and that's your file size. As for transfer rate:

```
final long start = System.nanoTime();
long charsRead = 0;
... do the transfer, counting chars ...
System.out.println("Transfer rate: " + 
  (charsRead / (1e-6 * (System.nanoTime() - start))));
```

The only problem here will be that you are using a `BufferedReader` so you count chars and not  bytes. If you need bytes, then you'll need to use the raw `InputStream` and then it's going to be a slight pain in the butt to find where the headers end. You can get around that (probably) by using not the `BufferedReader` but the `InputStreamReader`, which will not read-ahead anything. When you find the end of headers, switch to the raw `InputStream` to read the response body.